# Starting application on NFC tag detection

Tags: android-intent, xamarin, tags, nfc, intentfilter

I want to register an application to be launched when an NFC tag is detected. From searching around I found that I need to use

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { NfcAdapter.ActionTechDiscovered })]
```

on the main activity. However, the app doesn't launch (nor am I prompted to choose an application). Instead, a generic tag reader opens up.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ActionTechDiscovered` intent filter requires a tech-list that specifies the tag technologies (or combinations of them) that your activity should be started for. You can specify the tech-list file using:

```
[IntentFilter (new[]{NfcAdapter.ActionTechDiscovered})]
[MetaData (NfcAdapter.ActionTechDiscovered, Resource="@xml/nfctech")]
```

You then need to place a file "nfctech.xml" into the folder "Resources/xml". Inside this file you can define all the tag technologies that you want to listen to. For instance, to listen for any tag technology, you would use:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcBarcode</tech>
    </tech-list>
 </resources>
```

Comment: Awesome. Is there an easy way to define the technology list in a ClassLibrary project? I'd like to avoid having to define it in all (3) applications that exist in the solution.

Comment: Don't know, I've never used [tag:Xamarin]

Comment: Ah and one more question, regarding application lifecycle. When you hide the app and bring it back up, `OnResume` is called, however, I believe this solution closes and relaunches the application as `OnCreate` gets called, would that be correct? If so, is that the desired behavior?

Comment: From my experience with Android NFC, this seems to slightly change from version to version. From what I usually observed, it seems that if you manually started your activity, bring it to the background (actually bring your whole activity stack to the background) and then launch the activity through the NFC intent filter, a new instance of the activity is created (not quite sure if it's put on top of the existing activity stack of your app or if thats a new activity stack with the NFC service root activity as the root of the stack).